# need code to make video interactive, click curser/key to play next video

Tags: video, sequence, interactive

I have only just started with traditional coding so I'm going to need help with this. Any solutions, ideas, or resources would be very helpful!

I'm creating an art+coding piece and want to program it to be interactive.

What i want is essentially **a sequence of videos where after one video finishes the viewer has to click their mouse or press a key for the next video to play**

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: We'll be happy to help, but first you need to post your code as a [mcve], please see [ask].

Comment: If you are completely new to JavaScript, HTML, and CSS (ie front-end web developing), you should familiarize yourself by reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Video_and_audio_APIs

Comment: @ParisaT It's not obvious where you are stuck... Can you display a video on a web page? Is the problem in detecting when a video ends?